# Intel e810 nic RSS logic on ESXI platform

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, intel

I am trying to decipher how RSS (Receive Side Scaling) logic works for Intel NIC on ESXI (Dell) machine.

```
] vsish -e cat /net/pNics/vmnic2/rxqueues/info
rx queues info {
   # queues supported:8
   # rss engines supported:8
   # filters supported:512
   # active filters:1
   # filters moved by load balancer:31
   RX filter classes: 0x1f -> MAC VLAN VLAN_MAC VXLAN Geneve
   Rx Queue features: 0x482 -> Pair Dynamic GenericRSS
}
```

Is "Rx Queue features" denotes RSS algorithm?  Then where can I get more information on these items. Specifically I am intrested in which fields are taken into account while hashing?

Also how "Rx Queue features" related to "RX filter classes" , if at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Receive-side scaling* is the NIC's ability to use multiple receive queues with separate interrupts and subsequently separate processing on different CPU cores. Interrupt generation is usually controlled by a hash (over IP addresses and L4 port numbers), so each flow is processed by a specific core.

The *RX filter classes* are likely the details used for the distribution hash, and the *Rx Queue features* the algorithm used with the hash.

Comment: The hashing is done by the NIC I beleive based on the configured algorithm.  So it is not related to OS per se (ESXI in this case). The question is where I can get more information about exact details of the algorithms and how it can be configured in ESXI OS